# Capture photo using flask webserver on a Raspberrypi

Tags: python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi

This is my button calling the function, but when I press it, it is just refreshing the page.

```
href="{{ url_for('takephoto') }}"><input type="button" value="takephoto">
```

This is the part of code in app.py. All module are imported at the beginning:

```
@app.route('/camera',methods=['POST'])
def takephoto():
    os.system("sudo service uv4l_raspicam stop")        
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.capture(time.strftime("photos/%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S.jpg"))
    camera.stop_preview()
    camera.close()
    os.system("sudo service uv4l_raspicam start")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [capture to a stream](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-stream) then deal with that.

I don't have a Pi available to test right now, but something like:

```
import io
import time
import picamera

@app.route('/camera',methods=['POST'])
def takephoto():
    # Create an in-memory stream
    my_stream = io.BytesIO()
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.start_preview()
        # Camera warm-up time
        time.sleep(2)
        camera.capture(my_stream, 'jpeg')

    my_stream.seek(0)
    return send_file(my_stream.read(), mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Then have a separate route which renders the template:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

With this in the template:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('takephoto') }}" />
```

Reloading that page should capture a new image.